# When do I need to run "git pull --all"?

Tags: git

In order to know when I need to run `git pull --all` I run `git rev-parse origin/<branch name>` and `git ls-remote | grep <branch name>` if the SHA of the branch I got from rev-parse is different from the the SHA I got from ls-remote I know that I need to run `git pull --all`.

Today, I saw a problem with this idea, after I added a new branch to the git repository and run `git rev-parse origin/<new branch name>` I got `unknown revision or path not in the working tree`. Any idea how to know when I need to run `git pull --all` and support the case when I add new branches? In short, how to know if a new branch was add to the git repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you would never need to run `git pull --all` at all. With Git, you are always working on a single branch, so at any time, the current branch will be the only one you need to care about. Often, it’s even encouraged to keep your local branch outdated, so you can continue working without having to worry about upstream changes which might introduce changed features (that would impact your own current work), or even result in merge conflicts.

So usually, you would only run `git pull` *for the current branch*, if you actually want to update your current branch.

Another thing is fetching. Fetching, using `git fetch`, will update all your remote branches, receiving all changes from the remote repository and storing them in `origin/branch` branches (those are called remote branches because they belong to the remote). That way, you can update your local representation of the remote repository, making all its changes available to you. This will however *not* merge those changes into your local branches, so you still have full control over when and what to merge.

So if you want to have some information about what’s going on on the remote repository, you can regularly call `git fetch` to update your remote branches. This will always work and update whatever the remote has to offer—at worst, it will just tell you that there’s nothing new. It will also tell you which remote branches were updated, and when new branches were added, so that’s a good indicator for activity too.

And when you then decide that you really want to pull in the remote changes into your local branch, you can either run `git pull` (which internally fetches again for the current branch and then performs a merge), or just do `git merge origin/branchname` to merge the previously fetched changes manually into your local branch.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, how do I know if a new branch was added to the git repository? The system we are talking about is required for compiling code from several repositories, no development is done with those files. But if someone wants to compile the code from a new branch he just created the system needs to handle it correctly

Comment: The only way to see if there are any new branches on `origin` is to call `git fetch`.  This will update the list.  The distributed nature of git allows for you to develop code locally without having to be concerned with what the remote branches are doing.  Only when you ask git to will it check to see what is happening on the remote.

Comment: @e271p314 You know that by asking the remote to give you the information, with `git fetch`. If you only need that repository for compiling—and neither local code nor merges are involved—then you could do something like `git checkout origin/master` to just use the remote branch with a detached head without worrying about local branches at all. So you would run `git fetch` to update all remote branches, get a list of remote branches using `git branch -r` and then do your stuff on each by checking them out.

Comment: OK, indeed `git fetch` updates the the local copy with the new branches which were recently created by my entire purpose is to avoid the fetch (pull) operation. Eventually I found an easy workaround, `git ls-remote` prints the branch names, so I can use these names to know if a new branch was added.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid fetching?

Comment: To save time. git fetch and pull takes too long and I want to avoid it as much as possible. However, the build system must be right, i.e. if someone asks to compile the code from few specific branches even it he added them few moment ago, the system must return his the correct binary.